# Code does not excecute Firebase Database child event listener error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an android based app using Firebase as backend server. I have designed the Structure of the app in the following manner:

```
Project Name
|_ Products
|_ groups
   |_ 1BME
      |_ members
         |_ -K4usWDhtiw4U
             |_ Custom Object
         |_ -K4uscDHwYsXHs
             |_ Custom Object
```

The Custom Object is:

```
package com.app.shubhamjhunjhunwala.heritagecompanion_students;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

/**
 * Created by shubham on 23/01/17.
 */

public class UserDetails {

    UserDetails() {}

    public String name;
    public String email;
    public String password;
    public String phone;
    public String roll;
    public String department;
    public String year;
    public String section;
    public String dpDownloadUri;

    public UserDetails(String name, String email, String password, String phone, String roll, String department, String year, String section, String dpDownloadUri) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.roll = roll;
        this.department = department;
        this.year = year;
        this.section = section;
        this.dpDownloadUri = dpDownloadUri;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }

    public void setRoll(String roll) {
        this.roll = roll;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(String section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public String getDpDownloadUri() {
        return dpDownloadUri;
    }

    public void setDpDownloadUri(String dpDownloadUri) {
        this.dpDownloadUri = dpDownloadUri;
    }
}
```

My intention is to get the user details under members child under `1BME` under Groups child. So for this, I use the Following code in my program:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mGroupMembersDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("groups").child(groupRoll).child("members");

mGroupMembersDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                            UserDetails users = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserDetails.class);

                            Toast.makeText(GroupChatActivity.this, users.getRoll(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if (!users.getRoll().equals(senderRoll)) {

                                Toast.makeText(GroupChatActivity.this, users.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                mRecieverDatabaseReference = mRecieverDatabaseReference.child(users.getRoll()).child("groups").child(groupRoll);

                                Query query1 = mRecieverDatabaseReference.orderByChild("roll").equalTo(groupRoll);
                                query1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                            dataSnapshot1.getRef().child("state").setValue("unread");
                                            dataSnapshot1.getRef().child("timeID").setValue(timeID);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });

                                Messages message = new Messages(messageText, time, senderRoll, name, chatName, groupRoll, mState, messageType, "");
                                mRecieverDatabaseReference.push().setValue(message);

                                mRecieverDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("chats");
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

In this code String `groupRoll = "1BME"`

But when I run this code and debug it, I find that it never enters `onChildAdded()`. So please help me. The app isn't moving forward because of this.

Thank You.

Comment: isn't the parent starting with Project Name as root so  mDatabase.getReference().child("Project Name").child("groups").child(groupRoll).child("members");

Comment: I've used a lot of queries for the app. All of them work. But I've not used .Child("Project Name") in any of them. So it's basically neglected. Do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `DatabaseReference` is wrong. To get data from a member please use this code:

```
mGroupMembersDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("groups").child(groupRoll).child("members").child(memberId);
```

In which the `memberId` is unique id generated by the `push()` method.

Second, you don't need to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to change a value. Is wrong to use `setValue()` method on a `DataSnapshot`. You can use `setValue()` directly on your `reference`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is to inform you that what you are suggesting is just for getting the User Details for one user. I want the User Details of all members of the Group 1BME. So please try to help me accordingly

Comment: No, my suggestion was to get for all users. Because `memberId` is a variable and when you loop, this variable`memberId` becames every member. If i have suggested you in stead of `memberId` a particular id, let say `-K4usWDhtiw4U`, thant it would be for a particular member.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    UserDetails users = snapshot.getValue(UserDetails.class);
    //...
}
```